# WordPress request fiter order by related post's post_title

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta, request-filter

I have created two WordPresss custom post types (school, person). Each person is related to a school and the related school's post `ID` is stored in wp_postmeta under the person's post `ID` with `meta_key = 'person-school-id'` and `meta_value` = the related school's post `ID`.

I have added a `person-type` (Student, Teacher, etc. ) and the related School's name (by extracting the related school's `post_title`) to the Person WP edit.php list via `WP manage_person_posts_columns` and `manage_person_posts_custom_column` actions.

I have added filter capabilities for both `person-type` and `person-school-id` to the Person WP edit.php list via the WP `restrict_manage_posts` action.

And, I have added sort capabilities for the `person-type` to the Person WP edit.php list via the WP `request` filter using something like:

```
$vars = array_merge(
         $vars
        ,array(
             'meta_key' => 'person-type',
            ,'orderby' => 'meta_value'
        )
    );
```

So far, so good. All of this works as expected.

But, I also need to add sort capabilities for the related School's name (`post_title`). I could easily sort on the related Schools post `ID` (because that is what's stored in the person's wp_postmeta `person-school-id` `meta_value` field) by adding something like the following during the WP `request` filter:

```
$vars = array_merge(
         $vars
        ,array(
             'meta_key' => 'person-school-id',
            ,'orderby' => 'meta_value'
        )
    );
```

But I really need to order by the `post_title` (not post `ID`) of the post whose post `ID` is in the person's `meta_value` field for the `person-school-id` `meta_key`. Something like:

`,'orderby' => 'select post_title from wp_posts where ID = ' . meta_value`

Obviously, the above doesn't work.

All this to ask: How can I order by the `post_title` of a related post whose post `ID` is in a different post's wp_postmeta `meta_value` field while processing the WordPress `request` filter?

Answer (score 0):

After a short sleepless night with this running through my head, I have a solution that works. I'm not sure if it's the best solution but for those that may have a similar problem, here's what I did.

First, I abandoned trying to use the WordPress `request` filter for this particular ordering. Instead, I used the WP [posts_clauses](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses) filter as follows:

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'my_posts_clauses_filter', 20, 1 );
function my_posts_clauses_filter( $pieces )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'post_type' ] )
     and isset( $_GET[ 'orderby' ] )
     and 'person' == $_GET[ 'post_type' ]
     and 'person_school' == $_GET[ 'orderby' ]
     and ( 'ASC' == $_GET[ 'order' ] or 'DESC' == $_GET[ 'order' ] )
    )
    {
        $pieces[ 'join' ] .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} my_postmeta1 ON ( {$wpdb->posts}.ID = my_postmeta1.post_id AND my_postmeta1.meta_key = 'person-school-id' )";
        $pieces[ 'join' ] .= " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} my_posts1 ON ( my_posts1.ID = my_postmeta1.meta_value )";
        $pieces[ 'orderby' ] = 'my_posts1.post_title ' . $_GET[ 'order' ];
    }
    return $pieces;
}
```

That's it.

Once note of caution. This could have unintended consequences. I had another routine that used WP_Query to return a list of all schools for filtering. After adding the above `posts_clauses` filter, my get all schools routine was not returning anything when the `$_GET` entries were set. I got around this by surrounding the WP_Query request with a `remove_filter` and `add_filter` for the above `posts_clauses` filter.

Comment: Watch for possible SQL injections via the order GET parameter!

Comment: I've not gone through your exact setup, but I wonder if you can use the pre_get_posts action and modify the meta_query for the main query? Also the taxonomy queries usually perform better than post meta queries. So maybe custom taxonomies could be an alternative?